# Displacing polygon to larger intersection with several polygons using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, polygon, field-calculator, overlapping-features

I have a buffer that intersects with two polygons.

[image]

How can displace the buffer to the polygon with the largest intersection?

In addition

[image]

So far my code determines how many polygons my buffer intersects with, counts them, and adds them to a field called `"NUMPOLYGON"`

```py
layer1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("MERGE_PARCELAS")[0]

layer2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Polygon_sv")[0]
caps = layer2.dataProvider().capabilities()

if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.AddAttributes:
    res = layer2.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("NUMPOLYGON", QVariant.Int)])

layer2.updateFields()

layer2.startEditing()

for feat in layer2.getFeatures():
    feat['NUMPOLYGON'] = 0
    layer2.updateFeature(feat)

layer2.commitChanges()

layer2.startEditing()

for f in layer2.getFeatures():
    for j in layer1.getFeatures():
        if f.geometry().intersects(j.geometry()):
            if f['NUMPOLYGON'] != NULL:
                f['NUMPOLYGON'] += 1
                layer2.updateFeature(f)
                
layer2.commitChanges()
```

once the values ​​greater than one have been identified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this approach, it will move the small feature to the largest overlapping features centroid:

```py
def nameToLyr(layername):
    """Outputs a layer from a layername input"""
    return QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layername)[0]

def giveCentroidCoords(afeature):
    """Return x as y coordinates of a features centroid"""
    cent = afeature.geometry().centroid().asPoint()
    return (cent.x(), cent.y())

#Create layers
buffL = nameToLyr('buff')
largeL = nameToLyr('largelayer')

largeFeats = [f for f in largeL.getFeatures()] #List all large features

geometryMap = {} #A dictionary to hold each bufferlayers feature id and new geometry

for bfeat in buffL.getFeatures(): #For each bufferfeatures
    intersecting = [LF for LF in largeFeats if LF.geometry().intersects(bfeat.geometry())] #Find all intersecting features in large layer
    biggest = max(intersecting, key=lambda x: x.geometry().intersection(bfeat.geometry()).area()) #Find the one with the largest intersection area
    toX, toY = giveCentroidCoords(biggest) #Find the centroid coordinates of the largest overlapping feature
    fromX, fromY = giveCentroidCoords(bfeat) #Find the centroid coordinates of the buffer feature
    deltaX = toX-fromX #Calculate how much to move the buffer features in X direction
    deltaY = toY-fromY
    newgeom = bfeat.geometry() #Fetch its geometry
    newgeom.translate(deltaX, deltaY) #Move it
    geometryMap[bfeat.id()] = newgeom #Store it in the dictionary

buffL.dataProvider().changeGeometryValues(geometryMap) #Change the values
iface.mapCanvas().redrawAllLayers() #Redraw
```

[image]